# Get partner info from current user from odoo web api

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

Does anyone know how to get partner's info after authenticating the user via Odoo's web api without using the `res.users` model. Is there any endpoint to get these info?

Comment: Every user in Odoo in linked to partner because of the delegation inheritance between them.

you can just write a piece of code that return the current user id of the session then execute a sql statement that or ORM (search) to find out the related partner and print it's information

This is the scenario that you could implement.

Comment: so you mean I have to add some code on the server side to get this done? actually I'm requesting the user table with th api for the linked partner. but this solution forces me to use the admin credentials